# Date_format() ? Question help

Tags: php, mysql, date

If I have a MySQL table field of my one date with this format (09-13-2011 11:22:43), as I do for PHP to print with this format (09/13/2011 11:22:43) Sorry my ignorance I searched the php.net site but can not find something about my request, Apologies.

Comment: What is your question? Both formats look the same??

Comment: One uses hyphens, the other uses forward slashes.

Comment: Transform mysql field (09-13-2011 11:22:43) to PHP and print using this format (09/13/2011 11:22:43)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but...

The best way to store dates in MySQL is as a TIMESTAMP field type, which you then retrieve from the database and then format with PHP's `date()` function.

Comment: Yeah of course, The Mysql field type is TIMESTAMP :) , Ohh okay i will search documentation about the date() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
date( "m/d/Y h:i:s", UNIX_TIMESTAMP($fieldname));
```

If your field is already `timestamp` use the following:

```
date( "m/d/Y h:i:s", $fieldname);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I look very effective, but in my case for an unknown reason show this error: Strict Standards: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.

Comment: In that case use date_default_timezone_set('UTC') before the above code or whatever timezone is relevant to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$mysql_date = '09-13-2011 11:22:43';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s', $mysql_date);

echo $date->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: Your Answer is Right but i no have PHP > 5.3 to use the DateTime::add class, If you could show how to do the same in version 5.2.1

Comment: @Jonathan Edgardo: Then it's going to be nasty, don't try to handle this in PHP. Look at Álvaro G. Vicario's answer.

Comment: I like your intention Mate +Rep :)

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong in saying this but I don't think theres a standard way in doing so, unless you want to save the date/time as a unix_timestamp. If you do then you can format the time in however you want using the php date() function. If you aren't then you can always use something like str_replace() on the times to get them to the format you want or even use regex if your feeling adventurous

Comment: You're absolutely right in saying this, but I prefer to use the corresponding functions of PHP to manipulate dates. Many thanks

Comment: Yeah no worries, I just thought I'd give you a helping hand :)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's DATE columns format is fairly irrelevant. Just use [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to convert the date to a string that suits your needs.

Comment: Will seek additional documentation about it because php is giving me many problems.